# Drawing Horizontal Lines in Cocos2d with *consistent* widths

Tags: c#, xamarin, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d to draw simple horizontal lines with a consistent thickness. No matter what I set the line thickness to, some lines are always displayed thicker than others. It is as though there are certain display areas in the layer that "white out".

I have tried to make sure that the height of the view is always even or odd, or a multiple of any given number.  I have tried to make sure that the line lands on an even, odd or multiple of any given number. This happens at all display resolutions I have tried (width is multiple of 2, height is based upon the size of the physical display).

Nothing seems to help. I am using Xamarin with C# and this issue is present on both Android and iOS targets, both in the simulator and on actual devices.

Does anybody have any idea what I need to do differently so that horizontal lines are always displayed with the same thickness?